# Create a git server via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, server

**Goal**

My goal is to create a git repository, which, when he's update, sees its visible changes directly.

**Current situation**

The basic situation on the server is as follows:

```
/var/www/http/foo : index.html { foo }
```

I try to transform this folder into a repository, so I apply the following command:

```
serveur $ git clone --bare /var/www/http/foo foo.git
```

In order to make it more easily accessible in ssh, I do the following commands to create a shortcut at the root:

```
serveur $ mkdir git scp -r /var/www/http/foo/foo.git /git
```

From now, if I execute :

```
serveur $ git clone user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/git/foo.git
```

everythings work fine and I retrieve all the files.

I am now trying to push on the server from a client

```
client $ touch a
client $ git add .
client $ git commit -m "foo a"
client $ git push origin master
```

git informs me that everything went smoothly.
But if now, I go back to the server in the folder foo and I do the command ls, I do not see any changes.

If I try the command pull or fetch, i got this result :

```
serveur $ cannot be used without a working tree
```

However, if it deletes the repository of the client, and I clone it again, I will have the changes taken into account.

I would like to know how to make this work...

Comment: I think you are trying to "use" a bare repo.

Comment: I do not really understand that notion, would you have any links to that?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/

Comment: Ok so first of all i should not add the option --bare in the initialisation. 
Did you see any other things that lead this to failure ?